# Laravel route group match whole domain

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, dns, routes

I would like to be able to use different routes within my application for different domains. I would like to act differently depending on whether the domain is

- My own domain e.g. `mysite.com/something`
- A subdomain of my domain e.g. `subdomain.mysite.com/something`
- Any other domain e.g. `anotherdomain.com`

I've approach the problem like this:

```
// Match my own domain
Route::group(['domain' => 'mysite.com'], function()
{
    Route::any('/', function()
    {
        return 'My own domain';
    });
});

// Match a subdomain of my domain
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.mysite.com'], function()
{
    Route::any('/', function($subdomain)
    {
        return 'Subdomain ' . $subdomain;
    });
});

// Match any other domains
Route::group(['domain' => '{domain}'], function()
{
    Route::any('/', function()
    {
        return 'Full domain ';// . $domain;
    });
});
```

The first two groups work perfectly. Visiting `mysite.com` displays `My own domain` and visiting `subdomain.mysite.com` displayed `Subdomain subdomain` as expected. However, when I visit with `anotherdomain.com` (I have this set up as an alias in my vhost file as well as pointing it to the loopback IP in my hosts file), I get an `NotFoundHttpException`:

```
/var/www/portfolio/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php
```

Code:

```
    $others = $this->checkForAlternateVerbs($request);

    if (count($others) > 0)
    {
        return $this->getOtherMethodsRoute($request, $others);
    }

    throw new NotFoundHttpException;
}
```

Is there a way I can match any domain that is not my domain or a subdomain of my domain in this way? I need to be able to access the domain to do something with it afterwards too, just like I did with `$subdomain`.

Thanks,
Jonathon

Answer (score 10):

Was searching for this too...

Probably not the most beautiful solution, but it works

```
// Match my own domain
Route::group(['domain' => 'mysite.com'], function()
{
    Route::any('/', function()
    {
        return 'My own domain';
    });
});

// Match a subdomain of my domain
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.mysite.com'], function()
{
    Route::any('/', function($subdomain)
    {
        return 'Subdomain ' . $subdomain;
    });
});

// Match any other domains
Route::group(['domain' => '{domain}.{tld}'], function(){

    Route::any('/', function($domain, $tld){
        return 'Domain: ' . $domain . '.' . $tld;
    });
});

Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.{domain}.{tld}'], function(){

    Route::any('/', function($sub, $domain, $tld){
        return 'subdomain: ' . $sub . '.' . $domain . '.' . $tld;
    });
});
```

By the way, if you like to test it, add some fake domains to your HOSTS file, and point them to 127.0.0.1 :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that isn't possible because you have declared your domain in config/app.php.

You could try creating separate environment for second domain.

You can view how to use second domain in Laravel in [this tutorial](https://medium.com/laravel-4/laravel-4-multisites-26cdc75e4810).

Answer (score 0):

This is a late response, but you can do dynamic full domain routing without resorting to ugly extension hacks. By default, the Laravel domain filter applies a regexp that prevents you from using period characters in the value passed to the filter. Hence why it works when you break it out into segments, but not if you try to pass the full domain as a single parameter.

The easiest solution is to modify the pattern applied to the domain filter in the `boot` method of your `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` file as follows:

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    $router->pattern('domain', '[a-z0-9.]+');
    parent::boot($router);
}
```

This will allow you to send full domains through the filter.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't work for Laravel 4 (where this question was posted)

Answer (score -4):

Looks like the question is old. However, you could use the following:

Just remove the group part from the code as this will apply to any other domain

```
Route::any('/', function()
{
    return 'Full domain ';// . $domain;
});
```

Comment: Whoever down voted, would you mind sharing with us the reason for that? This is the correct way of using this site bytheway.

Comment: Read question carefully and answer what of the problems described in question did you solve by this post?